# set sender in event to variable

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listbox

I have 3 events that has to do with drag and drop.

```
    object originalSender;

    private void lstBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox curListBox = sender as ListBox;
        if (curListBox.SelectedItem == null) return;
        //this.lstLeft.DoDragDrop(this.lstLeft.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
        curListBox.DoDragDrop(curListBox.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        originalSender = sender;
    }

    private void lstBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }

    private void lstBox_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]);

        if (typeof(DataGridViewColumn).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
        {
            ListBox curListBox = sender as ListBox;
            Point point = curListBox.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            int index = curListBox.IndexFromPoint(point);
            if (index < 0)
                if (curListBox.Items.Count > 0)
                    index = curListBox.Items.Count - 1;
                else
                    index = 0;
            ((ListBox)(originalSender)).Items.Remove(obj);
            curListBox.Items.Insert(index, obj);
        }
```

The problem is that "originalSender" is null when lst_DragDrop method is run.  I am sure its because i am referencing the sender object that gets garbage collected and thus null.  How can I reference the list box that is the sender.

I have 3 ListBoxes all use this method so I need to know which one is being picked.

Comment: Try ListBox originalSender=(ListBox)sender;

Comment: Why not use a *private variable* that is returned?  Or better yet, an encapsulated field (Property) to store the value for usage throughout the life cycle?  Though you could do *instantation*, which should look like `((ListBox)sender).` something.

Comment: What's the difference between `sender` and `originalSender`? `sender` should give you the control that the event was triggered on. Isn't it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `originalSender = sender` statement before the call to `DoDragDrop`; `DoDragDrop` starts a new message pump on the same thread, so currently the statement is not executed until the end of the drag-drop operation.

---

As a side note:

> I am sure its because i am referencing the sender object that gets garbage collected and thus null

No, that's not possible. You got it backwards: the garbage collector never sets an object reference to null, it just collects objects that are not referenced anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the garbage collection.  Looked into it more and understand.